# Worklight: Changes for updating apns certificate or gcm key

Tags: android, iphone, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

If I update my `APNS` certificate or `GCM` key and re-deploy updated `*.wlapp` on worklight console,

Do I need to re-distribute my `.ipa` and `.apk` or only the server has to correspond with the certificate and key??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the APNS certificate and GCM key are server-side artifacts (in the case of Worklight-based apps, AFAIK), this means that they do not reside in the application.

The answer is, then: no, you are not required to re-distribute your applications to the App Store and/or Google Play.

Comment: And what do i need to re-deploy,.wlapp or .wladapter or both??

Comment: You need to re-deploy the .wlapp file.